# An ellipse centered at the origin and passing through two vectors

Tags: geometry

Given two vectors **a** and **b**, let **c** = **a** cos $\theta$ + **b** sin $\theta$. As we vary $\theta$ from $0$ to $2 \pi$,  **c** traces out an ellipse.

Can anyone tell me why this is true?

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ were the unit vectors of your coordinate system. Then the shape would be the unit circle, which is a special case of an ellipse. The transformation from these special vectors to generic $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ is a linear transformation, which in turn is an affine transformation. The image of an ellipse under an affine transformation is again an ellipse.

If this deduction is not useful to you, then you should be more explicit in what you know. In particular, what is your definition of an ellipse?